# Converting Face Into Shape in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

can anyone tell my how can achieve effect similar to this

[image: I picked this photo from SlideShare slide show]

in illustrator or any program, I'm an ios developer and designer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use live trace using the threshold option on illustrator or you can use photoshop by going to Image-->Adjustments-->Threshold and set the level as desired